# Random logo on page refresh and page load but always the same logo on first visit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script that picks a random logo for the site header. I want to make it so that 1 of them (in this case, the last image url) comes up as the first one when visiting the site.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
        (function newLogo() {
          var logos = [
            '<a href=/> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/t/60cb3ee08753fe223fd7c3fc/1623932640962/1.png"> </a>', 
                '<a href=/> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/t/60cb3ee3c536d32928855bd6/1623932643765/2.png"> </a>', 
                ' <a href=/> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/t/60cb3ee772267c3c5ade6a2f/1623932647615/3.png"></a>', 
                '<a href=/> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/t/60cb3eeaad4c8f605ed73a1a/1623932650130/4.png"></a>', 
            '<a href=/> <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/2f3a0f73-9cf3-4c93-83fa-1170945d58c6/fig.png"> </a>',
          ];
          var randomLogo = Math.floor(Math.random() * logos.length);
          document.getElementsByClassName('header-title-logo')[0].innerHTML = logos[randomLogo];
        })();
</script>
```

Comment: should the last image always come first and after that randomly choose?

Comment: If you want it the way Amal nandan has specified, you should make a variable `var firstUse = true` right before you declare the function and replace "`var randomLogo = Math.floor(Math.random() * logos.length);`" with :

`var randomLogo;if(firstUse){randomLogo = Math.floor(Math.random() * logos.length);}else{randomLogo = logos.length;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store if its the user's first time on the site

```js
function newLogo() {
    var randomLogo;
    var logos = [
        '<a href=/> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/t/60cb3ee08753fe223fd7c3fc/1623932640962/1.png"> </a>',
        '<a href=/> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/t/60cb3ee3c536d32928855bd6/1623932643765/2.png"> </a>',
        ' <a href=/> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/t/60cb3ee772267c3c5ade6a2f/1623932647615/3.png"></a>',
        '<a href=/> <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/t/60cb3eeaad4c8f605ed73a1a/1623932650130/4.png"></a>',
        '<a href=/> <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/60a13136b600dc692a87a25a/2f3a0f73-9cf3-4c93-83fa-1170945d58c6/fig.png"> </a>',
    ];

    if (localStorage.getItem('firstVisit') === null) {
      localStorage.setItem('firstVisit', true);
      randomLogo = logos[logos.length - 1];
    } else randomLogo = logos[Math.floor(Math.random() * logos.length)];

    document.querySelector('.header-title-logo').innerHTML = randomLogo;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar question with answers already exists - Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109201/with-javascript-how-would-i-increment-strings-using-an-array-to-create-a-loop/68109869 please close this question.